# Using git on amazon ec2

Tags: amazon-ec2, git

Hi i have been exploring around `ec2`. What i have come across is `elastic beanstalk` allows users to maintain their applications without much overhead of the scalability. But there are some limitations too using `elastic beanstalk` for use with **databases**, **memcache**. Recently beanstalk has started support for php also, with git. I have not yet been able to figure out that.

what i need to achieve run a few linux instances with **apache server**, **autoscaling** support and maintaining a **common repository** for all.

The query is that how servers are maintained in sync , do we need a versioning system `git` repository to do that.

Is something like this possible like creating a main central `git` repository in one `ec2` instance. And other `ec2` instances as `git` clients. Allowing to sync between all `git` clients with the repository.

Please guide. Also provide tutorial links, if any. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Sure it's possible to setup a git repo on one instance and have other EC2 instances pull from it.  This is equivalent to Elastic Beanstalk in the same way that an ox cart is equivalent to a formula one car.

Comment: thanks for your feedback. If that is the case, what should be the preferred approach ? =

Comment: Preferred approach for *what*?  You haven't provided a description of a problem that needs solving, merely an incomplete solution that you don't know how to implement.

Comment: preferred approach to managing the scalability of instances, and the data syncing among all running instances

Comment: Please put your question in a question, not a comment -- and provide sufficient detail for people to be able to give a useful answer to your specific situation.

Comment: i have modified my question

Comment: You would have been better off with a new question.